# How to pass values of an array across properties of different array objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, redux

1. List item

I have a redux store with this structure

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    currentData: [
        {
            title: 'Total Insurance Bought',
            img: 'insurance-bought.svg',
            bg: 'insurance-shield',
            data: '',
        },
        {
            title: 'Total Amount of Claims',
            img: 'amount of claims icon.svg',
            bg: 'amount-of-claims',
            data: '',
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the current structure of my reducer function

```
const summaryReducer = (state = INITIAL_STATE, action ) => {
    switch(action.type){
        case 'SET_SUMMARY_DATA':
            return {
                ...state,
                currentData: {
                    ...state.currentData,
                    data: action.payload
                }
            }
        default: 
            return state
    }
}
```

I would like to spread the values of this array in the action.payload, into each data property of the initial state while returning the whole state.

```
[ 0 , 20000 ]
```

I want my output to be

```
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    currentData: [
        {
            title: 'Total Insurance Bought',
            img: 'insurance-bought.svg',
            bg: 'insurance-shield',
            data: '0',
        },
        {
            title: 'Total Amount of Claims',
            img: 'amount of claims icon.svg',
            bg: 'amount-of-claims',
            data: '20000',
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: [ 0 , 20000 ] - Which of these values corresponds to `Total Insurance Bought` & `Total Amount of Claims`? How do you want your final output to be?

Comment: 0 should go to Total insurance and 20000 to total amount of claims

Comment: Ive posted my solution, hope it is helpful!

Answer (score 0):

If your current data is always going to have two array items and if expected payload is going to have two elements in expected order, you can do it this way.

```
case 'SET_SUMMARY_DATA':
  return {
     ...state,
     currentData: currentData.map((currentItem, index) => {
       currentItem.data = action.payload[index];
       return currentItem;
     })
  }
```